# GCP unexpected API calls

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

I am getting unexpected GCP charges relating to Virtual Machines. The customer service representative is yet to get back to me and I want to avoid cancelling billing if possible so I thought I would ask here.

I have a Kubernetes Cluster that was running a couple of nodes. Then I decided that I wanted to pause my project for a couple of months, so I scaled the cluster size to 0 with the expectation that I wouldn't be charged for running any VM isntances. However, I am still getting these charges even though the GCP console shows that I haven't got any VM instances running... Oddly, the API Dashboard shows that Compute Engine API calls are being made, which doesn't make sense because I don't have any VM isntances.

The Kubernetes Dashboard also says I have 0 nodes...

Could someone please suggest any ideas as to how I can get to the bottom of this?

Cheers

Comment: If we look at this page  https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/components/  we see that there are two components to a Kubernetes cluster ... the Master and the Nodes.  If you scale your cluster to zero nodes, does that not mean that the Master is still running and doing work?  Could that be the source of your resource consumption?

Comment: Did you use GKE or made a cluster using Compute Engine VM's ? I see few options here, but the safest will be to wait til the GCP support will tell you what is this related to. You can check for details in the API metrics in `Go to APIs overview`. A wild guess would be that your master API is still there or maybe there is some reservation for the components that you pay for.